# Blank space to right of entire page

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my css. I'm working on a wordpress template, and no matter what there seems to be blank space beyond 100% on the right.

Here's my css, any help is appreciated:

```css
/*
Theme Name: Linda Findlay
Theme URI: http://www.piercecreative.ca
Description: A clean and minimal theme that is completely compatible with WordPress 3.0
Author: Matthew Pierce
Author URI: http://piercecreative.ca
Version: 1.0
*/

body{  
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Georgia, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 980px;
}
a:link, a:visited{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

a:hover{
  color: #5f5f5f;
}

h1 a{
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-weight: 300;
}
#header h1 a:hover{
color: #101010;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#wrapper{
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 980px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;   
}
#wrapper2{
  width: 980px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #fff;
} 
#header{
  color: #ddd;
  margin-top: -40px;
  width: 980px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
#border{
width: 980px;
height: 1px;
background-color: black;
float: left;
margin-top: -20px;
}
#border2{
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
background-color: #fff;
float: right;
margin-top: -20px;
}
#metaslider_container_27{
margin-top: 100px;
width: 980px;
}
#blog{
  width: 980px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 0px 10px 0px;
}
.post{
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  float: left;
}
.post:last-child{
margin-right: 0px;
}
.entry{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.entry img{
  position:absolute;
  clip:rect(0px,300px,300px,0px);
}
.thumb{
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
} 
.thumb p{
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222;

}
#about{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 345px;

}
#cnt{
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#profile{
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}
#contact{
  background-color: #bababa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.sidebar{
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
}

#footer{
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
#contact-deets{
  float: right;
  width: 260px;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#contact-deets:hover{
  color: #333;
}
#contact-area {
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#contact-area input, #contact-area textarea {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 471px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 16px;
  float: left;
}

#contact-area textarea {
  height: 90px;
}

#contact-area textarea:focus, #contact-area input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

#contact-area input.submit-button {
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}

label {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.menu{
  margin-top: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #666;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}


.menu li{
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
.menu a{
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  padding:0 30px 0px 0;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-size:18px;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.menu ul ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  float:left;
  z-index:99999;
  background: #212121;
}

.menu ul ul ul{
  top: 30%;
  left:100%;
  background: #343434;
}

.menu ul ul a{
  height:auto;
  line-height:1em;
  padding:10px;
  width:130px;
}

.menu li:hover > a,.menu ul ul:hover > a{
  color:#333;
}

.menu ul li:hover > ul{
  display:block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px){
  body{
    max-width: 980px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
  #footer{
    width: 980px;
    max-width: 150%;
  }
  #footer p{
    margin-left: 33%;
  }
  .menu{
    width: 980px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #contact{
    width:  980px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 981px){
  .fix{
    margin-left: -50%;
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=27]"); ?> 
  <div id="blog"> <h3>RECENT WORK</h3><div id="border"></div>
    <?php query_posts('showposts=3'); ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post">
          <div id="1stp">

      <div class="entry">  
        <?php the_post_thumbnail();
        echo '<div class="thumb">' . '<p>' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt . '</p>' . '</div>'; ?>


      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <div id="about">
  <h3>BIO</h3><div id="border"></div>
    <div id="cnt"><?php
    $post_id = 38;
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
    echo $title;
    echo $queried_post->post_content;
    ?> 
    </div>
    <img id="profile" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSOyjuxygOjstEYLPtzJq4CJVGJu494MMmX3z7TBt5ss63WW_sXnw"/>
  </div>
  </div id="wrapper">
  </br>
  <div id="contact">
    <div id="wrapper2">
      <h3>CONTACT</h3><div id="border2"></div>
      </br>
      <div id="contact-area">

        <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
          <label for="Name">name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />

          <label for="City">city:</label>
          <input type="text" name="City" id="City" />

          <label for="Email">email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />

          <label for="Message">message:</label><br />
          <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
        </form>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

      </div>
      <div id="contact-deets">
        <?php
        $post_id = 53;
        $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
        echo $title;
        echo $queried_post->post_content;
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Will need to see the HTML that your CSS applies to.

Comment: Isn't it more likely that you forgot to close a existing div or something?

Comment: @j08691 Sorry! I've added the html.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but looking at your html I'm guessing the problem is that you close some divs when first opening them, try changing:

```
</div id="wrapper">
```

to

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

and check so you haven't done this somewhere else.

I also you think you're missing one last closing `</div>` at the end of your html, right before the `<php get_footer(); ?>` in other words you aren't closing you `wrapper` div correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That had affected some positioning issues I had, however the extra space still remains.

Comment: @Gantrof - I still think your problem is related to something in the html rather then in the stylesheet=) Have you checked so you haven't done the above at some other place? You should also check so you haven't forgot to add a closing `</div>` at some point.

Comment: @Gantrof - I have quickly looked over the html and I think you are missing one closing div at the end, right before `<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to not have that space would be to give `overflow:hidden` to your body but an example with jsfiddle with how your page looks would help more.

Comment: I considered using overflow:hidden, but then is there a way to have the page viewable with if the browser window isn't maximized?

Comment: you set the min-witdh to your body at 980px. less than that i can't be even if you minimize it. if you have your content put in your 980px width, your content will always be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file is ok problem is with your html tags.
check either you open and close tags accurately and closing tag must not contain any id or class but seems you have added wrapper class in closing div.